# Can the Heart-Shaped Herb be regrown?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018, black-panther-wakanda-forever

In *Black Panther*, we find

> Killmonger orders the elders to burn the rest of the Heart-Shaped Herbs so that no one else can become a Black Panther.

How will they be able to regrow the Heart-Shaped Herb? Is there a similar arc in the comics aligning with the *Black Panther* story line?

Comment: Answer seems to be "We don't know" and will find out in a later film, as far as I could research, in [all the mentions](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heart-Shaped_Herb/Appearances) of the Heart shaped herb in the comics it's never been "destroyed"

Comment: [What Shuri's Heart-Shaped Herb Discovery In Black Panther: Wakanda Forever Could Mean For The MCU](https://www.looper.com/1094368/shuri-heart-shaped-herb-super-soldiers-mcu-phase-6/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, but not naturally. The Wakandans were unable to naturally regrow the heart-shaped herb. What Killmonger ordered burned in *Black Panther* are the last of the Wakandans' naturally growing heart-shaped herbs.

In *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever*, due to the lack of heart-shaped herbs, Shuri was unable to use the herb to cure T'Challa's illness.

> **M'Baku:** That is because this wise council allowed Killmonger to take the throne and burn up all of your precious heart-shaped herb.

> **Shuri** (*to Killmonger*)**:** You burnt the herb, left us with no protector.

In the later part of *Wakanda Forever*, Shuri was finally able to recreate a synthetic heart-shaped herb by analyzing the fibers of the underwater plant from the bracelet K'uk'ulkan/Namor gave her. The underwater plant, like the heart-shaped herb, also grew because of the presence of vibranium in the soil.

> **Shuri:** Let's start by running a comparative analysis between our attempts at creating a synthetic heart-shaped herb... And the fibers from this bracelet.
> […]
> Since this was grown from vibranium-rich soil, they may share
> some base-level similarities that we can exploit.

Near the end of *Wakanda Forever*, it is revealed that there is now a new heart-shaped herb garden at Wakanda with several growing heart-shaped herbs, replacing the garden that Killmonger had ordered burned in *Black Panther*.

<sup>Note: This answer is copied from an answer of mine at the Movies & TV SE question, [Is there any way for Wakandan people to regrow the Heart-Shaped Herb?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/118990/1006)</sup>

Comment: Suggest an amendment to the Wakanda constitution banning heart shaped herb burning.

Comment: It would have made more sense to steal a live plant from Namor.  If dried out fibers from a bracelet are enough to Jurassic Park resurrect the herb it just demonstrates how the Wakandans in-universe messed up.  Not a single seed, dried leaf, root tip, cell sample, genome sequence anywhere.

Comment: Wait, wait. Namor is Kʼukʼulkan? I thought he was Tlāloc. I mean, he is literally the king of Tlālōcān (spelled differently, but still). A god of water I can understand, but a feathered serpent deity?

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way to regrow the herb.** This is a potential storyline of Black Panther 2, in which Shuri must become the Black Panther without the herb and use the tech instead to be the Black Panther. So no, the Herb is gone forever.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back up these bold assertions?

Comment: If Wakanda is as advanced as they seem then they should have seed banks and left a few to grow in the wild.

Comment: They've got an easy out, Steve Rogers could have known and definitely went back in time.

Comment: This answer now stands corrected by new canon, please check @galacticninja 's answer, as it explains this.