# Has the problem of the Legacy of the Black Panther ever been solved in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, black-panther

In Black Panther (2018), the following event happens

> After ingesting the heart-shaped herb, Killmonger orders the garden to be burnt, leading to all the herbs getting destroyed except one. That one is consumed by T'Challa.  Hence, as far as what we know, no heart-shaped herb is left. And no other way of gaining Black Panther's powers is shown in the movie.

Given that, has there ever been any mention ***in the comic universe*** of an alternative way of becoming a Black Panther?

Comment: Dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181753/can-the-heart-shaped-herb-be-regrown and therefore should be closed as per FWP.

Comment: Please search before asking questions.

Comment: @Edlothiad I am not asking only for opinions. I'm asking if there is anything mentioned about this **in comics**  ?

Comment: Are you asking if 1) The herb is the only way to become the Black Panther? 2) The herb can be regrown again? 3) If there will be any more Black Panther's after T'Challa? Also closing as opinion based is for questions which violate the Future works policy.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I am asking **can** there be any Black Panthers in future. So the answer of either question *1* or *2* of your comment shall answer my question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot BTW, What is the *Future Works Policy* ?

Comment: See [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/should-we-add-an-off-topic-close-reason-for-future-works). In short questions about future works are closed until that work becomes available.

Comment: While your's isn't _necessarily_ about a future work, we can be _almost_ certain that this _will_ be answered in a future work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the Future Works Policy

Comment: Yes @Edlothiad we can of course *expect* it to be answered in future movies. But as I have already stated my question is not in reference to future movies but to **present comics** .

Comment: Then you should remove the MCU tag. The two continuities are not always compatible.

Comment: Not even people's deaths are permanent in the Marvel universe. Why should this be permanent? They will pull another herb or something similar out of someones behind if they need it for the next dozen movies. The other answer has a comment that in the comics, the herb seems to have never been destroyed, so the answer to that is "We don't know.".

Comment: comics != movies. Future works close is correct because the MCU isn't necessarily beholden to any comic history

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh - In addition to the points above - You are asking about a movie event that is not depicted in comics, and asking if it's already been resolved in the comics? Or are you intending to ask if the HSH has been destroyed in the comics before?

Comment: @JohnP I am not referring to burning of the garden in the comic. My question says ' *Is any alternative way of becoming Black Panther mentioned in the comics* ?

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh - In that case, I have edited your question to make that more clear.

Comment: Two words: seed bank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes.

Erik Killmonger's plan went somewhat differently in the comics.  He never destroyed the herb gardens, so the Black Panther legacy was never put in jeopardy.  However, there *is* an alternate way of gaining the Black Panther's powers.

In the comics, Killmonger settled in Wakanda and became an established citizen, then staged a coup while the Black Panther was away on an Avengers mission and ate the Heart-Shaped Herb in order to gain the Black Panther's powers.  However, since he wasn't a member of the royal bloodline, his body rejected the herb.  He never had the opportunity to destroy the gardens because, well, he [went into a coma.](http://worldofblackheroes.com/2011/07/31/the-heart-shaped-herb/)

After his recovery, he eventually developed a [synthetic version](http://collider.com/black-panther-heart-shaped-herb-explained/) of the herb. This might be the solution they go with in the MCU. T'Challa's sister Suri at one point eats the herb herself, so it wouldn't be surprising if, in the movies, it's *she* who develops the synthetic.

Comment: Or, possibly, there's another smaller herb garden, perhaps a nursery, that they conveniently neglected to mention to Killmonger. It's somewhat difficult to eliminate every single sample of any plant - they can rebuild with one or two.

Comment: I didn't recall Suri eating it, though, good catch.

Comment: @VBartilucci That's definitely a possibility, but it's unrelated to OP's question.